# Dropdown list checkboxes in angular2 material design

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I would like to create a dropdown list with checkboxes so the users can select multiple options in Angular 2 using Material Design.

By default, I would like to have all the checkboxes checked. How do we do this?

This is my code which works fine for creating the DDL with checkboxes:

```
<md-select multiple placeholder="Section List" [value]="section" options="true"  (ngModelChange)='checkedSection();'>   
   <md-option *ngFor ="let section of selectedSectionList"  >
     {{section.sectionTitle}}
</md-option>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another example that probably looks a little more like what yours will look like...

You need the `[value]` to be passed in the `<md-option>` tag, not the `<md-select>` tag.

You can use `[(ngModel)]` to implement two-way data binding with a variable that initially holds the full set of all options. This variable will change based on user input. If a user unchecks a box, that value will be dropped.

So we need another variable to iterate over for the options, so that they still show up when they are unchecked.

Then you can use *ngFor to iterate over another variable containing all options to display.

```
selectedSectionList = [{'sectionTitle': 'Title 1', 'sectionOther': 'awesome stuff'},
    {'sectionTitle': 'Title 2', 'sectionOther': 'awesome stuff'},
    {'sectionTitle': 'Title 3', 'sectionOther': 'awesome stuff'},
    {'sectionTitle': 'Title 4', 'sectionOther': 'awesome stuff'},
  ];

  sectionsSelected = this.selectedSectionList;
```

and your HTML would look like this

```
<md-select multiple placeholder="Section List" [(ngModel)]="sectionsSelected">
  <md-option *ngFor ="let section of selectedSectionList" [value]="section">
    {{section.sectionTitle}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [value] to be passed in the `<md-option>` tag, not the `<md-select>` tag.

For example, this works:

```
 sectionsSelected = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
 AllSections = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
```

Then in your html

```
<md-select multiple placeholder="Section List" 
[(ngModel)]="sectionsSelected">
  <md-option *ngFor ="let section of AllSections" [value]="section">
    {{section}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```